# Passing javascript array to function from onclick property

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, onclick

i'm dynamically generating some buttons with a loop from a json file with an onclick event attached that passes some values and an array to a function.

Something doesn't work since i get a generic "unexpected identifier" error in the console when clicking the button; if i replace the array with a string or a number the script works meaning that there must be something wrong in my way of passing the array or in the array itself.

This is what the buttons html output looks like (why are there two [object object]?):

```
<button onclick="myFunction(1,'string',{[object Object],[object Object]})">Click me</button>
```

Generated from

```
var button = '<button onclick="myFunction('+otherArray.value1+',\''+otherArray.string1+'\',{'+myArray+'})">Click me</button>';
```

This is what the array looks like in chrome console just before generating the buttons:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {param1: "1", param2: "text"}
1: {param1: "2", param2: "more text"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: where is the loop that you are using to generate that string?

Comment: Sounds like a job for event delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason because you see `[object Object]` is because for how you assign the `onclick`, for those values the `toString` method will be called, so the output is `[object Object]`.

First suggestion I could give you, is that in these cases where you have to assign such attributes, use `addEventListener`, rather than creating the hardcoded element in this way.

So in your case something like:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");        
var t = document.createTextNode("Click me");
button.appendChild(t);
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myFunction(otherArray.value1, otherArray.string1, { myArray });
});
// then append the button where you want to
```

Comment: It's part of a much bigger script, i'll try to implement this solution but at the moment i don't have how to append the object since the button output is basically a string of text.
In case i can't implement it this way, is there an alternative?

Comment: I managed to find where the html was generated in the plugin (i previously could only pass a string to the plugin and it did the rest, hence the choice to use the onclick property), created the element and attached the event to it. Thank you